# web3.eth.contract is not a function when making contract

Tags: web3js, dapps, javascript, nodejs, ethereumjs

Whenever I try and make a contract, I get:

> web3.eth.contract is not a function

I'm using this code:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

// Compile the source code
let input = fs.readFileSync('./contracts/ProofOfExistence3.sol', 'utf8');
let output = solc.compile(input, 1);

let abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':ProofOfExistence3'].interface);
let bytecode = output.contracts[':ProofOfExistence3'].bytecode;

let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode}).then(console.log);

// Contract object
let MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
```

And if I only run this code below, I get undefined. The same code works in the browser but not in nodejs with the official web3 package.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

console.log(web3.eth.contract);
```

Returns undefined.

Any ideas? I'm running "testrpc" locally.

Comment: I think this may be because you are using the new web3 1.0.0-beta.11. Try the documentation from https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#eth-contract, or with the previous version 0.20.0.

Comment: Maybe if you try with `MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAdress)`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but i'm using geth and its default console running a private chain builted up with geth+puppeth. I deploy my contract simply pasting the web3deply code from remix in the client console (opened by geth) then i instanciate the contract on a var using var myContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI); on any client of my chain. Now i call its functions using: myContract.at("0x9f8cedf1f93e46fac74cb9415db8bbec85f239b4").method(); Is this the right procedure? I mean, the other one listed on web3 documentation does not work for me, since i get back Contract is not a function I a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Ismael suggested, **setting the web3 version to 0.20.0 in my package.json** allowed me to use this code.

```
npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3@0.20.1
```

Ideally, I would update my code to work with latest package but happy with this solution for now.

Comment: switching to 0.20.0 also worked for me, I could get the instance of the contract with: `let svd = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, scAddress);` but wasn't able to call functions, always throw an error `cannot read property length`

Comment: @Sepultura I encountered the same issue

Comment: It worked for me as well - my usage: npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3@0.20.1

Answer (score 34):

Solution:

```js
MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
```

Docs https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#eth-contract

When using version `1.0.x` you need to pass in the Application Binary Interface, i.e. `abi`. And use the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 10):

I came this issue when I use web3 0.19.

For web3 1.0:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545/'));

new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contract_address, {from: address})
```

Comment: With a capital C on *Contract* !

Answer (score 5):

Adding to answer from @David

Smartcontract with **web3 1.0.0-beta.31**

In 1.0.0-beta... most is handled via **Promises** now, hence you could do:

```
var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract({abi}, '0x123....', {
    from: '0x456...', // default from address
    gasPrice: '20000000000' // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this case
});
```

Example: Get **Token Balance**:

```
MyContract.methods.balanceOf('0x456...').call()
    .then(function(result){
    //the result holds your Token Balance that you can assign to a var
    var myTokenBalance = result;
    return result;
});
```

- Where `{abi}` is the ABI Interface of your Contract `0x123....`.
- Where `0x123....`    is the address of your Contract.
- Where `0x456....` is the address of your Ethereum Account that holds
  the Tokens (i.e. the ETH account you wish to retrieve its Token Balance from)

Note:
I am using the **IPC** Provider `geth.ipc` to interact with my node (as I am on the same PC, localhost, hence more save instead of using HTTP request).

```
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    var net = require('net');
    var web3 = new Web3('/home/yourHomeFolder/.ethereum/geth.ipc', net);
  };
```

That way you shouldn't get the error anymore

> web3.eth.contract is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Requires `c` capital of contract(Here: `web3.eth.Contract`), So it should be

```
var contractAbi = new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
```

look that is `C` and not `c`  in: `web3.eth.Contract`

Answer (score 0):

Installing web3 version  0.20.0 will resolve the issue.
To install,

```
npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3@0.20.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547268/smart-contract-method-is-not-a-function-in-web3)

You just need to install a stable version of Web3:

```
npm install web3@^0.19.0 --save
```

Comment: I'm using this version itself and yet getting error: `contract.deploy is not a function`.
Any ideas?