# Deploy contract on EthereumJS TestRPC

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, web3j

Following https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2

I've tried to create an instance of a contract using:
`VotingContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition)` but I get: `TypeError: web3.eth.contract is not a function`
So I've tried: `VotingContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiDefinition)` as suggested here: [web3.eth.contract is not a function when making contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22983/web3-eth-contract-is-not-a-function-when-making-contract)

But then when I try to deploy the contract on my test blockchaing (launched with EthereumJS TestRPC) I get the following:

```
deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Rama','Nick','Jose'],{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})
TypeError: VotingContract.new is not a function
    at repl:1:38
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:44:33)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:239:29)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:433:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:278:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:625:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:905:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:502:7)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:157:10)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at emitKeys (internal/readline.js:420:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
    at ReadStream.onData (readline.js:1006:36)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:239:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:197:10)
    at TTY.onread (net.js:589:20)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your `web3.version`? I found today that at some point after 1.0.0-beta.11 a bunch of the contract creation functionality broke, so I reverted from .15 to .11 and it's working again.

Comment: I had `web3@1.0.0-beta.16`, I've tried to move to `web3@1.0.0-beta.11` using `npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.11` as you suggested but I get the same error.

Comment: With web3@0.20.1 I've been able to deploy the contract

Comment: I am facing same issue and I am new to this kind of environment. Found any solution??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API for the web3.js v1.0 changed. The tutorial is using the web3 api v0.x.x.
Thus, you must either update your node to use the proper API

```
npm install ethereumjs-testrpc web3@0.20.1
```

or, you must update the code to use the v1.0 implementation. I.E:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
```

You can also refer to the github from mjhm who did a great job converting the tutorial code to v.1.0.
https://github.com/mjhm/hello_world_dapp

Answer (score 0):

Use `VotingContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiDefinition)`. Worked for me.

Comment: The question is asking about deployedContract = VotingContract.new , he has already added the VotingContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiDefinition) in the previous line.

Comment: In your `package.json` file, add: `"dependencies": { "web3": "0.14.0" }` instead of version 1.0 beta

Comment: The tutorial uses the 0.x not version 1.0. Took me a while to realise that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `deploy` function as shown in web3.js docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy as well as the `asciiToHex` utility function.

Prior to initializing the contract instance, type the following into your node console:

```
// to use the asciiToHex utility function
asciiToHex = Web3.utils.asciiToHex;

// put array of candidates into a variable
candidates = ['Rama', 'Nick', 'Jose'];

// set first test account testrpc created into account variable
web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => { account = accounts[0] });
```

Deploy the contract to the blockchain.

```
VotingContract.deploy({data: byteCode, arguments: [candidates.map(asciiToHex)]}).send({from: account, gas: 4700000}).then((result) => {deployedContract = result});
```

`deployedContract` is now the instance of the contract. You can check this by typing `deployedContract.options.address` into your node console.