# How to deploy a smart contract in a server?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, solc, linux, server-side

I have developed a smart contract and compiled it with solc and bin and abi fils have been generated. Now, I want to deploy this contract using web3js in a linux server. How can I do it?

Comment: you can setup a private chin or a single geth node in your server. otherwise use ropsten network thorough metamask or myethewallet.

Comment: @ Badr Bellaj Thank you, but could you tell me how to setup a single geth node in server ? also, Do I need to install web3 i.e. npm install web3 ?

Comment: as you are new to the field, if you want just to test your code try to use instead testrpc or truffle. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23842/deploy-contract-on-ethereumjs-testrpc

Comment: @ Badr Bellaj Yes I am new to this field, but I have to deploy it in server. I fouhttps://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/2021/badr-bellajnd a javascript file that is apparently for deploying the contract https://gist.github.com/tomconte/4edb83cf505f1e7faf172b9252fff9bf but question is that how to use this file in server ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To deploy a smart contract on ethereum, you have to make a deployment transaction.

A deployment transaction is send contract bytecode to empty address.

For example:

My add.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;


contract ADD {
    uint256 total;

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) public {
        total = a+b;
    }
}
```

The bytecode of add.sol
`608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060b88061001f6000396000f3fe6080604052600436106039576000357c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090048063771602f714603e575b600080fd5b348015604957600080fd5b50607d60048036036040811015605e57600080fd5b810190808035906020019092919080359060200190929190505050607f565b005b808201600081905550505056fea165627a7a72305820e3f9b94abc880b4f5646678c218c6c79a98f8dad3a566a9822548d539b741a340029`

The deployment transaction looks like:

```
{
    from: "0x......", // you have to unlock account first
    to: null,
    gas: 2000000,
    gasPrice: 1000000000,
    value: 0,
    data: "0x60806040523480156......"
}
```

You can call send transaction rpc through curl:

```
curl -vX POST localhost:8545 -d '{"method": "eth_sendTransaction", "id": 1, "params": [{"transaction object"}]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Alternative you can call send raw transaction rpc if you want to sign with own private key:

```
curl -vX POST localhost:8545 -d '{"method": "eth_sendRawTransaction", "id": 1, "params": ["0x................."]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 0):

so in a nutshell :

**first**: deploy a geth node in your server. here's a detailed tutorial https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/how-to-create-your-own-private-ethereum-blockchain-dad6af82fc9f

**second**: once your node is running use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/), connect it to your node RPC address and deploy directly from remix.

otherwise you can explore the solutions described in my comments to your post.